# intuition on the projection formula

Tags: algebraic-geometry

For a morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$, locally free sheaf $\mathcal{G}$ on $Y$, and a quasi-coherent sheaf $\mathcal{G}$ on $X$, we have the projection formula
$$f_*(\mathcal{F}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}f^*\mathcal{G})\simeq f_*\mathcal{F}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_Y}\mathcal{G}.$$

I don't have a problem proving this, but I have a hard time seeing it as a projection! This looks more like compatibility of pushforward with base change if we take $\mathcal{G}=\mathcal{O}_Y$. What is the  motivation for calling it the projection formula?

Comment: $G$ doesn't have to be quasi-coherent.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In my case, for example, I need to apply this formula to the natural projection
$$ \pi: X\times \operatorname{Div}_X \to \operatorname{Div}_X $$
where $X$ is a curve and $\operatorname{Div}_X$ denotes the set of effective Cartier divisors on $X$.

**I guess the name comes from the fact that one often faces these kind of situations.**

Intuitively, if you have a projection $\pi : X\times Y \to Y$ and sheaves $\mathscr{F}$ on the product and $\mathscr{G}$ on $Y$, you can consider the pullback $\pi^*\mathscr{G}$, which is constant on the fibers of the projection. You can tensor it with $\mathscr{F}$ above, obtaining
$$ \mathscr{F}\otimes \pi^* \mathscr{G} $$
and wonder what happens if you push this down again to $Y$. Well, under the above mentioned hypothesis, this statement ensures that the pushforward sheaf is what you expect it to be:
$$ \pi_* \mathscr{F} \otimes \mathscr{G} $$
i.e. the pushforward of $\mathscr{F}$ tensored with the plain $\mathscr{G}$.

[image: Visualization]

Comment: thanks for the lovely picture!